# Weird results when use numpy.random.seeds(0)?

Tags: python, numpy, random, tensorflow

I found something weird when using numpy.random.seed(0) to get reproducible results.

```
import numpy as np
def a():
    print('a', np.random.rand())
    b()
def b():
    print('b', np.random.rand())
    c()
def c():
    print('c', np.random.rand())
np.random.seed(0)
a()
```

The result is:

```
a 0.5488135039273248
b 0.7151893663724195
c 0.6027633760716439
```

And if I change the code to:

```
import numpy as np
def a():
    np.random.seed(0)
    print('a', np.random.rand())
    b()
    print('aa', np.random.rand())
def b():
    np.random.seed(0)
    print('b', np.random.rand())
    c()
def c():
    np.random.seed(0)
    print('c', np.random.rand())

a()
```

The results would be as follow:

```
a 0.5488135039273248
b 0.5488135039273248
c 0.5488135039273248
aa 0.7151893663724195
```

It's really weird, I was using tensorflow to train my finance sequence predict model, and I want to get reproducible results. It seems that I need to call np.random.seeds() before every time I use random function. Anyone has better solution?

Comment: What is it that you find weird here?

Comment: What is it that you're expecting?

Comment: Why would that be weird? That is exactly how a pseudo-random generator works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
random.seed(int)
```

initializes a random generator which has always the same list of "random" numbers. In your code you initialize the generator in every procedure. But when you print aa, your generator jumps to an other number.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I had a misunderstanding of random seeds.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializating the seed of a rng before every call. The way a rng works is that it gives "random" numbers after the initialize seed. In your case, with the seed being always the same, it just gives you the first value of the sequence every time.

```
def b():
     np.random.seed(0)
     print('b', np.random.rand())
     c()
```

I think it's a copy-paste mistake, because you have it right on the first example. Anyways here you have some info about rng. [Wikipedia RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)